# Cleanest way to create a Hash from an Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

I seem to run into this very often.  I need to build a Hash from an array using an attribute of each object in the array as the key.

Lets say I need a hash of example uses ActiveRecord objecs keyed by their ids
Common way:

```
ary = [collection of ActiveRecord objects]
hash = ary.inject({}) {|hash, obj| hash[obj.id] = obj }
```

Another Way:

```
ary = [collection of ActiveRecord objects]
hash = Hash[*(ary.map {|obj| [obj.id, obj]}).flatten]
```

Dream Way:
I could and might create this myself, but is there anything in Ruby or Rails that will this?

```
ary = [collection of ActiveRecord objects]
hash = ary.to_hash &:id
#or at least
hash = ary.to_hash {|obj| obj.id}
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

There is already a method in ActiveSupport that does this.

```
['an array', 'of active record', 'objects'].index_by(&:id)
```

And just for the record, here's the implementation:

```
def index_by
  inject({}) do |accum, elem|
    accum[yield(elem)] = elem
    accum
  end
end
```

Which could have been refactored into (if you're desperate for one-liners):

```
def index_by
  inject({}) {|hash, elem| hash.merge!(yield(elem) => elem) }
end
```

Comment: I think if you change the merge to merge! you'll avoid creating a bunch of intermediate hashes you don't need.

Comment: If you are going to use this many times in the critical path of you app, you might want to consider using ary.index_by{|o| o.id} instead of using symbol_to_proc.

Comment: `index_by` seems to be a duplication of Ruby's `group_by`. Am I missing anything?

Comment: group_by has an array as the value, whereas index_by assumes there's only one item per key so the value is that single item, not an array.

Comment: `['an array', 'of active record', 'objects'].index_by(&:id)` fails with error NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for "an array":String using Rails 4.2.5 and Ruby 2.3.0

Comment: The example is not self contained, the strings are representing, as their contents suggest, active record objects, which has an id method :)

Answer (score 10):

a shortest one?

```
# 'Region' is a sample class here
# you can put 'self.to_hash' method into any class you like 

class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.to_hash
    Hash[*all.map{ |x| [x.id, x] }.flatten]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 9):

In case someone got plain array

```
arr = ["banana", "apple"]
Hash[arr.map.with_index.to_a]
 => {"banana"=>0, "apple"=>1}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can add to_hash to Array yourself.

```
class Array
  def to_hash(&block)
    Hash[*self.map {|e| [block.call(e), e] }.flatten]
  end
end

ary = [collection of ActiveRecord objects]
ary.to_hash do |element|
  element.id
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the [Ruby Facets Gem](http://facets.rubyforge.org) and use their [Array.to_h](http://facets.rubyforge.org/doc/api/core/classes/Array.html#M000131).

Comment: I wouldn't recommend adding a dependency for a simple method