# Sorting an array using another array

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I was looking for a way to sort an array using another array. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961685/sort-an-array-according-to-the-elements-of-another-array) was an answer that worked for me:

- The order_array (an array of ids in a weird order that I want): `a1 = [34, 54, 12, 43]`
- The list of objects (that I want to order): `a2 = [ {id: 54, name: "greg"}, {...}, {...}, {...} ]`
- `a2.sort_by{|x| a1.index x.id}`

What is going on with this little piece of code?

Comment: `a1.index(x.id)` returns `x`'s position in the `a1` array. `sort_by` uses that info to sort the `a2` array.

Comment: ahhh... so, 

a1.index(x.id)           means we are assigning index values to each id

kinda like [3, 5, 2, 6].index(2)  would give me '2' as the answer.  and then from there we are just sorting by those index values, which of course will be 0,1,2,3,4,5, etc!

Answer (score 2):

What happens here is that `sort_by` uses the block you pass to it to map the array into sortable elements. This way the elements can be compared using the `<=>` method. All comparable objects must implement this method, in this case integers.

`sort` uses a sort algorithm (probably not bubble sort, taking the return value of the block as the value being sorted.

So, this expression:

```
a2.sort_by { |x| a1.index x.id }
```

... would yield the same results as running:

```
a2.map { |x| a1.index x.id }.sort
```

... where `x.index(x.id)` returns the index of the current element's id property in the `a1` array.