# How to sort one array based on another array using Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

There are two arrays:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
B = [3, 4, 1, 5, 2, 6]
```

I want to sort `B` in a way that for all the elements of `B` that exists in `A`, sort the elements in the order that is in array `A`.

The desired sorted resulted would be

```
B #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I have tried to do

```
B = B.sort_by { |x| A.index }
```

but it does not work.

This question differs from the possible duplicates because it deals with presence of elements in the corresponding array and no hashes are present here.

Comment: _"elements of B that exists in array A"_ – what about elements that don't exist in A?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort an array according to the elements of another array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961685/sort-an-array-according-to-the-elements-of-another-array)

Comment: I have placed my comment regarding possible duplicate @WandMaker

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It perfectly works:

```
▶ A = [1,3,2,6,4,5,7,8,9,10]
▶ B = [3,4,1,5,2,6]
▶ B.sort_by &A.method(:index)
#⇒ [1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 5]
```

If there could be elements in `B` that are not present in `A`, use this:

```
▶ B.sort_by { |e| A.index(e) || Float::INFINITY }
```

Comment: Looks like there is no need to make the check that I did in my answer :) Good answer.

Comment: Although it fails for elements in B that are not in A. Try to delete element `3` from `A`

Comment: Works perfect ! Thanks

Comment: Works until you don't have elements from B in A.

Comment: @radubogdan Good catch, updated. I do not think that your decision to drop inexisting in `A` elements is OK.

Comment: My decision to drop inexisting elements in A was to make a point and create a better answer :) I did upvote you from the beginning anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I would start by checking what elements from B exist in A :

```
B & A
```

and then sort it:

```
(B & A).sort_by { |e| A.index(e) }
```

Answer (score 2):

First consider the case where every element of `B` is in `A`, as with the question's example:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
B = [3,6,1,5,1,2,1,6]
```

One could write the following, which requires only a single pass through `A` (to construct `g`<sup>1</sup>) and a single pass through `B`.

```
g = A.each_with_object({}) { |n,h| h[n] = 1 }
  #=> {1=>1, 2=>1, 3=>1, 4=>1, 5=>1, 6=>1, 7=>1, 8=>1, 9=>1, 10=>1}
B.each_with_object(g) { |n,h| h[n] += 1 }.flat_map { |k,v| [k]*(v-1) }
  #=> [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 6]
```

If there is no guarantee that all elements of `B` are in `A`, and any that are not are to be placed at the end of the sorted array, one could change the calculation of `g` slightly.

```
g = (A + (B-A)).each_with_object({}) { |n,h| h[n] = 1 }
```

This requires one more pass through A and through B.

Suppose, for example,

```
A = [2,3,4,6,7,8,9]
```

and `B` is unchanged. Then,

```
g = (A + (B-A)).each_with_object({}) { |n,h| h[n] = 1 }
  #=> {2=>1, 3=>1, 4=>1, 6=>1, 7=>1, 8=>1, 9=>1, 1=>1, 5=>1}
B.each_with_object(g) { |n,h| h[n] += 1 }.flat_map { |k,v| [k]*(v-1) }
  #=> [2, 3, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 5]
```

This solution demonstrates the value of a controversial change to hash properties that were made in Ruby v1.9: hashes would thereafter be guaranteed to maintain key-insertion order.

<sup>1 I expect one could write `g = A.product([1]).to_h`, but the doc [Array#to_h](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h) does not guarantee that the keys in the hash returned will have the same order as they do in `A`.</sup>

Comment: If every element of `B` is in `A`, this solution is definitely the most elegant.

Comment: @mudasobwa, I made some changes that may interest you.

Answer (score 1):

You just missed `x` in `A.index`, so the query should be:

```
B = B.sort_by { |x| A.index(x) }
```