# Sort list of objects according to an array (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have an array if ids from a table e.g:

```
b = [659, 658, 656, 645, 644, 657, 634, 643, 649, 650, 651, 636, 633, 607, 605, 604, 648, 647, 675, 674, 667, 499]
```

I use it for retrieving a list of objects from tat table:

```
k = Photo.where(id:b)
```

What I get is a list of objects which are NOT sorted in the same order as the array.

How can I do that?

Comment: It looks like your answer may be here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961685/sort-an-array-according-to-the-elements-of-another-array

Comment: @jvillian thanks - your are right. There are several suggestions in the thread. I didn't go with the ticked answer. Instead I went with this http://stackoverflow.com/a/25297497/3508526

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## If ids are unique

You can use [index_by](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/Enumerable/index_by) and [values_at](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) :

```
k = Photo.where(id: b).index_by(&:id).values_at(*b)
```

Example :

```
b = [5,3,1]
Country.where(id: b)
#=> [#<Country id: 1, name: "France">, #<Country id: 3, name: "Ukraine">,  #<Country id: 5, name: "Spain">]
Country.where(id: b).index_by(&:id)
#=> {1=>#<Country id: 1, name: "France">, 3=>#<Country id: 3, name: "Ukraine">, 5=>#<Country id: 5, name: "Spain">}
Country.where(id: b).index_by(&:id).values_at(*b)
#=> [#<Country id: 5, name: "Spain">, #<Country id: 3, name: "Ukraine">, #<Country id: 1, name: "France">]
```

## If b contains duplicate ids

With `b = [5,3,3,1]`, the first method would output :

```
#=> [#<Country id: 5, name: "Spain">, #<Country id: 3, name: "Ukraine">, #<Country id: 3, name: "Ukraine">, #<Country id: 1, name: "France">]
```

You can use [index_by](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/Enumerable/index_by) and [slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-slice):

```
k = Photo.where(id: b).index_by(&:id).slice(*b).values
```

With :

```
b = [5,3,3,1]
Country.where(id: b)
#=> [#<Country id: 1, name: "France">, #<Country id: 3, name: "Ukraine">,  #<Country id: 5, name: "Spain">]
Country.where(id: b).index_by(&:id)
#=> {1=>#<Country id: 1, name: "France">, 3=>#<Country id: 3, name: "Ukraine">, 5=>#<Country id: 5, name: "Spain">}
Country.where(id: b).index_by(&:id).slice(*b)
#=> {5=>#<Country id: 5, name: "Spain">, 3=>#<Country id: 3, name: "Ukraine">, 1=>#<Country id: 1, name: "France">}
Country.where(id: b).index_by(&:id).slice(*b).values
#=> [#<Country id: 5, name: "Spain">, #<Country id: 3, name: "Ukraine">, #<Country id: 1, name: "France">]
```

Of course, you could also use the first method with `b.uniq`

Answer (score 1):

An ActiveRecord query like `Photo.where(id: some_array)` produces SQL like this:

```
select ... from photos where id in (...)
```

but the order of elements in the `IN` has no relation to what order the database returns the rows in; in general, the only thing that determines the order of the rows is the ORDER BY clause.

You can get the database to order things to match your `b` array with a CASE:

```
order by case id when 659 then 0 when 658 then 1 ... end
```

and that's fairly easily to construct in Ruby:

```
Photo.where(id: b)
     .order(%Q{case id #{b.map.each_with_index { |id, i| "when #{id} then #{i}" }.join(' ')} end })
```

Not terribly pretty I suppose but it gets the database to do the work (which might be important if you're chaining more things into this query) and you can easily hide the ugliness inside a class method on Photo:

```
def self.for_ids_in_order(ids)
  where(id: ids).order(%Q{case id #{ids.map.each_with_index { |id, i| "when #{id} then #{i}" }.join(' ')} end })
end
```

and then say `Photo.for_ids_in_order(b)`.

Of course, this does assume that you know where the `b` array came from and that you know it contains integers. If you're not certain of that then you can throw a `connection.quote` call in to make sure things are properly escaped:

```
ids.map.each_with_index { |id, i| "when #{connection.quote(id)} then #{i}" }...
```

Answer (score 0):

**b.map { |m| Photo.find(m) }** if the ID's in b array are unique. If not
then run this **b.uniq.map { |m| Photo.find(m) }**
One drawback of this code is it runs a query for every elements present inside b array.