# Sort multiple fields based on selection

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, sorting

I have a dropdown that can be toggled to 3 states - ascending, descending and none. The dropdown rearranges the items in my list.

[image]

**My code:**

**list.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; index as i">
  <ui-list-item
      [body]=getItem(item)"
  ></ui-list-item>
</div>
```

**list.component.ts**

```
getItem(item){
     const toggle = {Price: true, Active: false, Modifiers: true}
     let list = [
         {label:"Price", value:item.price}, // e.g. "$10.00"
         {label:"Active", value:item.active}, // e.g. true
         {label:"Position", value:item.position} // e.g. 1
         {label:"Category", value:item.category} // e.g. "Food"
     ];
     return list;
}
```

When the value in toggle is true, the items are arranged in ascending order. When the value in toggle is false, it is in descending order.

How do I implement the sort function in the order of toggle values left to right? (For example, if price comes before position, etc.) And as the labels contain different type of values, how do I detect the type and sort accordingly?

I've found this [How to sort an array of objects with labels according to other array of labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58606533/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-with-labels-according-to-other-array-of-labels) but it doesn't seem to be working.

Updated answer (but still not working)

```
getItem(item){
 const toggle = {Price: true, Active: false, Modifiers: true}
 let list = [
     {label:"Price", value:item.price}, // e.g. "$10.00"
     {label:"Active", value:item.active}, // e.g. true
     {label:"Position", value:item.position} // e.g. 1
     {label:"Category", value:item.category} // e.g. "Food"
 ];

list = list.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      if (typeof toggle[a.label] === 'boolean') {
        if (toggle[a.label]) return a.value - b.value;
        else return b.value - a.value; 
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
 });

 return list;
```

}

Isit because I'm not retrieving the entire list to sort? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
list = list.sort((a:any, b:any) => {
    if(a.label !== b.label){ // if labels are not equal sort by label
        return a.label.localeCompare(b.label) 
    }
    if(typeof toggle[a.label] == 'boolean'){
      if(toggle[a.label])
        return a.value.localeCompare(b.value)
      else
        return b.value.localeCompare(a.value)
    } else {
      return 0
    }
    }
```

Comment: hi gokul, thank you for your solution. the list is not sorting according to the labels though, like "price" is ascending and "active" is descending

Comment: Oh i get it you want to sort all entries with label 'Price' in ascending , with label 'Active' in descending like that right?

Comment: i think this is what you are looking for.But this sorts the array based on labels also

Comment: hi I've updated my post, the list still doesn't seem to be updating. The code you've given looks correct though, is it cause I'm not retrieving the entire list to sort?

Comment: check now it was because a - b cannot be used to compare two strings

Comment: I'm still not able to sort.. is it cause I'm calling getItem(item) from html side and not retrieving the entire body?

Comment: Yes. Inorder to sort I think you have to sort items array instead.